# ObservableCollection's IEnumerable ctor finalizes collection, but the IList ctor does not

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, observablecollection

In the following method, when I copy the `IEnumerable` result to a list with `ToList()`, **no finalizers are called** at the `ObservableCollection`'s `IList` constructor, and the `IDisposable` view-models only get finalized upon program closure:

```
private void ReadHeaders()
{
    IList<PlanningGridHeaderVM> viewModelSet =
        (from header in _planningGridService.ReloadHeaders().OrderBy(x => x.PlanNumber)
         select new PlanningGridHeaderVM((PlanningGridHeader)header)).ToList();

    foreach (PlanningGridHeaderVM headerVM in viewModelSet)
    {
        ItemEditedEventManager.AddHandler(headerVM, OnItemEdited);
        PropertyChangedEventManager.AddHandler(headerVM, OnPropertyChanged, string.Empty);
    }

    this.ViewModels = new ObservableCollection<PlanningGridHeaderVM>(viewModelSet);
    CollectionChangedEventManager.AddHandler(this.ViewModels, this.OnCollectionChanged);
}
```

However, when I use the `IEnumerable` result directly in the `ObservableCollection`'s `IEnumerable` constructor, my Debug output informs me that all of the `IDisposable` view-model items are being **finalized by the GC at that point** (this is what puzzles me).

Nevertheless, I still get the desired collection on-screen, and upon program closure, they all get **finalized again** (this time, as expected):

```
private void ReadHeaders()
{
    IEnumerable<PlanningGridHeaderVM> viewModelSet =
        (from header in _planningGridService.ReloadHeaders().OrderBy(x => x.PlanNumber)
         select new PlanningGridHeaderVM((PlanningGridHeader)header));

    foreach (PlanningGridHeaderVM headerVM in viewModelSet)
    {
        ItemEditedEventManager.AddHandler(headerVM, OnItemEdited);
        PropertyChangedEventManager.AddHandler(headerVM, OnPropertyChanged, string.Empty);
    }

    this.ViewModels = new ObservableCollection<PlanningGridHeaderVM>(viewModelSet);
    CollectionChangedEventManager.AddHandler(this.ViewModels, this.OnCollectionChanged);
}
```

**Why?** The MSDN pages for both ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653202%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) say *"The elements are copied onto the ObservableCollection in the same order they are read by the enumerator of the collection."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case, you're actually evaluating the query twice. Once when you use `foreach`, and then another time when you create the `ObservableCollection`. You'll end up with two distinct sets of objects, which you could validate by adding some debug information in the `PlanningGridHeaderVM` constructor.

Iterating over the query results the first time doesn't actively finalize it - there's no such concept. However, the objects returned will be immediately eligible for garbage collection unless your `AddHandler` methods retain a reference to them.

In the first case, you're only evaluating the query once, because `ToList()` will *materialize* the query. It's basically taking the query, evaluating it and remembering the results - so then when you iterate over it with `foreach` and then create an `ObservableCollection` from it, both of those loops will operate on the same collection of objects.